# Вывести файл без последней строки с помощью head

Tags: linux, bash, unix, head

Пытаюсь сделать так:

`head -n -1 file`

Но получаю ошибку:

`head: illegal line count -- -1`

head вроде бы поддерживает отрицательные аргументы. В чём же проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отрицательные индексы
в `head` — это расширение
*GNU*. [Документация](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html)
к *POSIX* `head` говорит ясно:

> […]  The application shall ensure that the number option-argument is
> a positive decimal integer.

Можете использовать `sed`, удалив из входного потока
(**не** из оригинального файла)
последнюю строку:

```sh
$ sed -e '$d' ./file.txt
```

(Либо поставить более свежий набор
*GNU*'тых инструментов.)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно сделать что-то такое:

```
 head -$((`wc -l test | awk '{print $1}'` -1)) test
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам это уже написали, на всякий случай напишу более прямо: у вас не GNU/Linux, поэтому не смотрите man, который относится к GNU coreutils. У вас на маке будет отличаться набор параметров.